# React states button or create back button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications

I'm not a developer and I'm currently blocked. I'm trying to create a "go home" button or hide this restart button and show it to the user only when he reaches the last view. I can't find a solution...

Thanks in advance for your help.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { SelectSign } from './components/SelectSign';
import { SelectTimeframe } from './components/SelectTimeframe';
import { Horoscope } from './components/Horoscope';

function App() {
  const [selectedSign, setSelectedSign] = useState(null);
  const [
    selectedTimeframe,
    setSelectedTimeframe,
  ] = useState('today');

  const restart = () => {
    setSelectedSign(null);
    setSelectedTimeframe('today');
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>The Horoscope App</h1>
      {!selectedSign && (
        <SelectSign onSignSelected={setSelectedSign} />
      )}
      {selectedSign && !selectedTimeframe && (
        <SelectTimeframe
          onTimeframeSelected={setSelectedTimeframe}
        />
      )}
      {selectedSign && selectedTimeframe && (
        <Horoscope
          sign={selectedSign}
          timeframe={selectedTimeframe}
        />
      )}
      <button onClick={restart}>Restart</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: When do you want it to hide the restart button exactly. Please clarify.

Comment: When <SelectSign> is selected. Or when Horoscope is show.
I have only 2 steps : User select her sign and i show off her horoscope. (i have bepass the selection day for only show the currennt day)

Answer (score 0):

When **selectSign** button is clicked you are setting the value in the **selectedSign**.
You can check if else condition here using ternary operator in the JSX template.

If **selectedSign** value is present then show **GO home** button else it will show **Restart** button.

```js
function App() {
  const [selectedSign, setSelectedSign] = useState(null);
  const [
    selectedTimeframe,
    setSelectedTimeframe,
  ] = useState('today');

  const restart = () => {
    setSelectedSign(null);
    setSelectedTimeframe('today');
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>The Horoscope App</h1>
      {!selectedSign && (
        <SelectSign onSignSelected={setSelectedSign} />
      )}
      {selectedSign && !selectedTimeframe && (
        <SelectTimeframe
          onTimeframeSelected={setSelectedTimeframe}
        />
      )}
      {selectedSign && selectedTimeframe && (
        <Horoscope
          sign={selectedSign}
          timeframe={selectedTimeframe}
        />
      )}
      {
       selectedSign?<button>Go Home</button>:<button onClick={restart}>Restart</button>
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: working perfectly, i add class for hide the restart button. thanks   prathameshk73

Comment: @niavlys  you can mark answer as accepted.